# ms_access Run time error 3078 in VBA although query runs as saved query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I keep getting this error but everything appears to be correct:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim vStartTime As String
Dim vDate As String
vTime = Forms!frmEditDay!cmbStartTime
vDate = Forms!frmEditDay!cmbDate
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = """SELECT tblSpring2022.ID, tblSpring2022.fldDate, tblSpring2022.fldTime, tblSpring2022.fldUserName " _
            & vbCrLf & "FROM tblSpring2022 " _
            & vbCrLf & "WHERE (((tblSpring2022.fldTime) = " & Chr(34) & vTime & Chr(34) & ") And ((tblSpring2022.fldDate) = " & Chr(34) & vDate & Chr(34) & ")) " _
            & vbCrLf & "ORDER BY tblSpring2022.fldTime;"""
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

When I attempt to run this I get Run-time error '3078':

The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query "SELECT tblSpring2022.ID, tblSpring2022.fldDate, tblSpring2022.fldTime, tblSpring2022.fldUserName
FROM tblSpring2022
WHERE (((tblSpring2022.fldTime) = " 0800") And ((tblSpring2022.fldDate) = "3/2/2022"))
ORDER BY tblSpring2022.fldTime;"

although the query works perfectly from the Query Builder (I just swiped and copied it to VBA).

What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, for testing purposes I skinned the query down to:      """SELECT * FROM tblSpring2022"""  I've checked the table (repeatedly), it exists in Currentdb, it's name is spelled "tblSpring2022", I can open it and it has 394 entries.  But still I get:  "Run-time error '3078'  The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query '"SELECT * FROM tblSpring2022"'.  Make sure it exists and that the name is spelled correctly."  I confess this puzzles me as, so far as I can tell, what I've got is exactly like any number of (presumably working) examples here and elsewhere.

Comment: Back around the circle.  I went back to where I started, with a saved query called quyDailySignInEdit:  SELECT *
FROM tblSpring2022
WHERE (((tblSpring2022.fldTime)=Forms!frmEditDay!cmbStartTime) And ((tblSpring2022.fldDate)=Forms!frmEditDay!cmbDate));  and called it from VBA:  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("quyDailySignInEdit")  But now I got the error that I started this whole process off:  Run-time error '3061':  Too few parameters.  Expected 2.  It was searching for a fix for that that led me to a site that advised me I should put the query directly in VBA, which in turn led me here.

Comment: I'm kinda lost here.  How exactly do I get VBA to open a recordset based on a query?  Certainly seems that it ought to be possible.  Thanks.